# Android - version

Tags: android

I have created an app and tested it on android API16 and API19 and it works, but when i tested it on API18 give error at start

```
03-13 11:17:25.884: E/AndroidRuntime(2678): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-13 11:17:25.884: E/AndroidRuntime(2678): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.arr_app/com.arr_app.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-13 11:17:25.884: E/AndroidRuntime(2678):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2137)
03-13 11:17:25.884: E/AndroidRuntime(2678):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
03-13 11:17:25.884: E/AndroidRuntime(2678):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
03-13 11:17:25.884: E/AndroidRuntime(2678):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
03-13 11:17:25.884: E/AndroidRuntime(2678):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-13 11:17:25.884: E/AndroidRuntime(2678):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-13 11:17:25.884: E/AndroidRuntime(2678):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
03-13 11:17:25.884: E/AndroidRuntime(2678):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-13 11:17:25.884: E/AndroidRuntime(2678):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
03-13 11:17:25.884: E/AndroidRuntime(2678):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
03-13 11:17:25.884: E/AndroidRuntime(2678):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
03-13 11:17:25.884: E/AndroidRuntime(2678):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-13 11:17:25.884: E/AndroidRuntime(2678): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-13 11:17:25.884: E/AndroidRuntime(2678):     at     android.content.ContextWrapper.getApplicationInfo(ContextWrapper.java:146)
03-13 11:17:25.884: E/AndroidRuntime(2678):     at com.arr_app.DBHelper.<init>(DBHelper.java:31)
03-13 11:17:25.884: E/AndroidRuntime(2678):     at com.arr_app.MainActivity.<init>(MainActivity.java:44)
03-13 11:17:25.884: E/AndroidRuntime(2678):     at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
03-13 11:17:25.884: E/AndroidRuntime(2678):     at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1130)
03-13 11:17:25.884: E/AndroidRuntime(2678):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1061)
03-13 11:17:25.884: E/AndroidRuntime(2678):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2128)
03-13 11:17:25.884: E/AndroidRuntime(2678):     ... 11 more
```

project have `Minimum Required SDK: API8` and `Target SDK: API18`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `MainActivity` as a `Context` too early before `onCreate()`, at constructor/member variable initialization phase.

Move your `DBHelper` initialization to `onCreate()`.